# How to add formatted text to a word document in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I take just a substring of text (but formatted, so it will keep it bold/italic/in a table) from one Word document and add it to another in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off copying the whole think, paste it in the new document and do some string replacements.